# How to get single array of hits using multisearch API in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 7.9
Below is the multisearch query I wanted to execute.

```
GET /sample/_msearch
{}
{"query": {"match":{"first_name":"John"}}}
{}
{"query": {"match":{"last_name":"Doe"}}}
```

My problem is I am getting different hits for both queries. I need all the hits should be in one  array. And even if I have a document with John Doe then that document is repeating in both hits.

How do I get distinct documents in the single hit. (At least duplicates in single hit is also fine.)

If I get in multiple hits then it will be difficult to paginate.

Small hint is also appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html), instead of [Multi-search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) (if you are querying on a single index)

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "first_name": "John Doe",
  "last_name": "Doe"
}
{
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "first_name": "John"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "last_name": "Doe"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67642002",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.39343077,
        "_source": {
          "first_name": "John",
          "last_name": "Doe"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67642002",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.34276456,
        "_source": {
          "first_name": "John Doe",
          "last_name": "Doe"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. Actually my query is pretty large. So, I have posted a dummy query. Basically I am making union of three large queries. I thought of execute it like multi search query. Please suggest me a better way for this.

Comment: @ManonandanSK are you querying on different indexes ? Or all the search queries are for the same index ?

Comment: On the same index.

Comment: @ManonandanSK You even want that all the hits of the search queries, must be in the same array (that means you want to combine the result of multiple queries into a single one), so according to me you should use boolean query (along with `must/should/filter` clause according to your use case.

Comment: @ManonandanSK you can easily combine the queries using boolean query and its clauses. Let me know if you have any further doubt?

Comment: I have two array in which various colors are stored in one array and size is stored in another array. first selected size and color combination will be given higher preference and then second selected combination, then third selected and so on. If I use boolean query on array of color and size I am not getting the document with size-color combination selected first. That's because more relevant document will be having more score. Please suggest your thoughts.

Comment: @ManonandanSK can you please explain your use case, with the help of some sample index data and expected search result (in JSON format), so that it would be more clear ?

Comment: I have created another thread [Ordering and preference in Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67646297/ordering-and-preference-in-elasticsearch). please refer to this and help me out. Thank you.

Comment: Yes. I am planning to move to boosting with bool query.