# Ordering and preference in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch 7.9

**Index Data**(single index)

```
{
  "color":["white", "red"],
  "size":["XL", "XXL"]
}
{
  "color":["white", "red"],
  "size":["L", "XXL"]
}
{
  "color":["black", "red"],
  "size":["XL", "XXL"]
}
{
  "color":["black", "red"],
  "size":["L", "XXL"]
}
{
  "color":["white", "black", "red"],
  "size":["L", "XXL"]
}
```

**Expected result**

```
[
  {
    "_index": "stack_sample_1",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "XTtZknkBYSYF3m_h2Du3",
    "_score": 1.4352849,
    "_source": {
      "color": [
        "white",
        "red"
      ],
      "size": [
        "XL",
        "XXL"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "stack_sample_1",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "cztaknkBYSYF3m_hjTtL",
    "_score": 2.0163896,
    "_source": {
      "color": [
        "white",
        "black",
        "red"
      ],
      "size": [
        "L",
        "XXL"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "stack_sample_1",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "XjtZknkBYSYF3m_h3ztp",
    "_score": 1.0988126,
    "_source": {
      "color": [
        "white",
        "red"
      ],
      "size": [
        "L",
        "XXL"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "stack_sample_1",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "YDtZknkBYSYF3m_h5juX",
    "_score": 1.4352849,
    "_source": {
      "color": [
        "black",
        "red"
      ],
      "size": [
        "XL",
        "XXL"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_index": "stack_sample_1",
    "_type": "_doc",
    "_id": "YTtZknkBYSYF3m_h7Ts8",
    "_score": 1.0988126,
    "_source": {
      "color": [
        "black",
        "red"
      ],
      "size": [
        "L",
        "XXL"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Basically I want to give preference in the order of

1. white,XL
2. white,L
3. black,XL
4. black,L

**I tried**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "color": "white"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "size": "XL"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "color": "white"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "size": "L"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "color": "black"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "size": "XL"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "color": "black"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "size": "L"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I am not getting expected result.
In my output the doc having white, black, XL is on the top as it has most relevant matching.
I don't want that order of result.

Please Help me.

Small hint is also appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can use [boosting query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-boosting-query.html) with the combination of the [bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)**

```
{
  "query": {
    "boosting": {
      "positive": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "color.keyword": "white"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "size.keyword": "XL"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "color.keyword": "white"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "size.keyword": "L"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "color.keyword": "black"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "size.keyword": "XL"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must": [
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "color.keyword": "black"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "term": {
                        "size.keyword": "L"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "negative": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "color.keyword": "black"
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "size.keyword": [
                    "XL",
                    "L"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "negative_boost": 0.5
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67646297",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.7944039,
        "_source": {
          "color": [
            "white",
            "red"
          ],
          "size": [
            "XL",
            "XXL"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67646297",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.3714104,
        "_source": {
          "color": [
            "white",
            "red"
          ],
          "size": [
            "L",
            "XXL"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67646297",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "5",
        "_score": 1.3714104,
        "_source": {
          "color": [
            "white",
            "black",
            "red"
          ],
          "size": [
            "L",
            "XXL"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67646297",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.89720196,
        "_source": {
          "color": [
            "black",
            "red"
          ],
          "size": [
            "XL",
            "XXL"
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67646297",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 0.6857052,
        "_source": {
          "color": [
            "black",
            "red"
          ],
          "size": [
            "L",
            "XXL"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

---

**And if you are not having a document that has both `white` and `black` color, then you can try this simplified version of the above query**

```
{
  "query": {
    "boosting": {
      "positive": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "color.keyword": [
                    "white",
                    "black"
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "size.keyword": [
                    "XL",
                    "L"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "negative": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "term": {
                  "color.keyword": "black"
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "size.keyword": [
                    "XL",
                    "L"
                  ]
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "negative_boost": 0.5
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great. Thank you so much.

Comment: I have one concern. I have to use many attributes like design, fabric etc. Can I use the same to do query on all the attributes?

Comment: I have to add every thing to negative except the one I want to give highest priority right?

Comment: @ManonandanSK you will add those attributes in negative, for which you want less priority (that means you want to decrease the score when these attributes come)

Answer (score 0):

Since the relevance scores are not what you want, you will have to use custom scoring. There are a few options :

1. Weight will let you give more importance to a field than others.
2. Boost will let you give more importance to a field **value** than others.

There are some very good explanations on the internet. You can use this [article](https://compose.com/articles/elasticsearch-query-time-strategies-and-techniques-for-relevance-part-ii/) besides the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/app-search/current/relevance-tuning-guide.html).